# Applying mutation in a GA to solve the Traveling Salesman

Tags: implementation, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman, mutation

I'm working on an mini academic assignment to solve the Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP) using a Genetic Algorithm (GA). I'm following a very simple classic representation storing cities and tours in arrays, for instance a 10 cities tour could be represented as 9-1-0-4-3-8-6-5-2-7 and so on.
Having a rather basic knowledge of GAs, I'm a bit confused on what sort of approach you would follow to apply different types of mutations to the TSP. Let's say our route is represented as route, and the mutation rate is represented in the variable m_rate.

**[1]  Simple insertion mutation**

Say we have: 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9. Then we pick a random city, say index 5 and then pick a random insertion index like 2, then the mutated chromosome is:  1-2-6-3-4-5-7-8-9.

Now here is what I'm doing to apply mutation:

```
for (int i=0; i<route.length; i++) {
 if (m_rate<Math.random()) {
 // Pick a random city
 int randomCity =  0 + (int)(Math.random() * ( ((route.length-1) - 0) + 1));
 // Do the insertion and shift the array where appropriate
 }
}
```

In other words I'm looping through every city in the route and seeing whether the mutation condition holds (m_rate>Math.random()), if it does then I stop at that index and then randomly pick an insertion point without the use of the mutation probability variable. 
As long as the end of the array has not been encountered I continue to apply the same thing to the every other remaining city or index. 
Is this a correct approach ? Should I stop or break out of the loop once I apply the first mutation ? Should the mutation probability be involved somehow in selecting the insertion point ? though that doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me.
If there is a chance that more than one city is mutated in the chromosome or route, is it possible that the chromosome is remutated ? in other words what would happen if I end up doing a second or third mutation inverting the chromosome to its initial form (before mutating) ?

**[2] Reciprocal exchange mutation.**

Choose a random city in the chromosome and then choose a second random city and exchange the two. For instance, in a route 1-5-2-8-0-9-3-7-4-6. If we end up choosing index 2 and index 7, then the mutated chromosome is: 1-5-7-8-0-9-3-2-4-6.

I'm following a similar approach to the above insertion mutation by traversing through every city in the route and checking the probability condition and then directly choosing a random city to exchange with without applying any sort of mutation rate. The same sort of questions above apply here..

**[3] Inversion mutation.**

This is the most tricky one. Given a chromosome like: 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9, we choose a mutation cut like index 2 to index 5 and then invert that subroute ==> 1-2-6-5-4-3-7-8-9.

But how do you apply this ? Do you loop through the route and then pick a city based on the mutation rate and then directly choose another index to determine the length of the subroute ? do mutate once and exit ? In this sort of implementation, can the whole chromosome or route be mutated inverting the whole thing if we the mutation cut end up being 0-9 or 0-(length-1) ? in this case what is really the value of the mutation rate ? I'm sort of lost here...

I apologize in advance for making this too long.. but I would appreciate any comments on those issues, or maybe if someone could direct me to any resources where those things are discussed in detail. I have looked at a number of research papers out there, but not many have approached this sort of specifics and details.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options when you choose a mutation:

- You can allow the mutation to produce invalid/illegal chromosomes and score them poorly.  This means the GA will be searching both for correctness (weeding out illegal results) and an optimal result.
- You can write a mutation function which only produces valid/legal outputs.

The first option may let you write a simpler, more natural mutation of your chromosome.  However, you will probably have to extend the representation (allow 12 or 15 slots for your 10 city tour, for example) and the algorithm will take longer to converge.  Your score function may be more expensive if it has to evaluate correctness.  You can be flexible in how your chromosome is interpreted (for example, ignoring the second occurrence of a destination) or not.

The first option may also simplify your implementation of crossover for the same sorts of reasons.

The second option will usually converge faster, but it can be harder to avoid subtle biases in the mutation function that influence your results.

Your suggested representation and mutations are similar to non-GA approximations to TSP which rely on exchanges followed by tests for improvement.  Simulated annealing is one way to decide which transpositions to accept.

A GA implementation may need an entirely different sort of chromosome to make crossover and mutation natural.

Comment: hi Ben, thank you for the comment. I'm honestly not sure what you mean by non-GA approximations, I found this representation to be widely used even among researchers when using GA, mainly for its simplicity. I have considered using a 2D-matrix representation but that does not allow any sort of flexibility in crossover and mutation and it's a bit sophisticated to implement. As for the mutation and crossover I'm definitely following the second option you pointed out, not using a penalty function and ensuring that every resulting chromosome is legal or valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best choice is use inversion for mutation and for crossover use OX (ordered). I wrote a GA for solving TSP and it works very good. In my case when apply inversion I choose two random points (it could be the whole string) but not the same points.The best results where with a rate of 0.2/0.3 for mutation and 0.8 for crossover but this will depend on your selection mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Inversion is usually the best working mutation operator for solving the TSP. You can download and experiment with [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com) which includes more such mutation operators and crossovers. It allows you to define experiments where you can run your GA a couple of times with each operator and see which is working best. There are some video tutorials that should help get you started. It's open source so you can also look at the implementation.